# Paypal Express Checkout payment method missing in magento frontend

Tags: magento, paypal

I have installed magento 1.7.0.2 and I've enabled paypal express checkout, but it never shows as a payment method in the checkout process of magento.

I've tested enabling other payment methods, such as credit card payment, check, and they all work only if paypal express checkout is disabled. When I enable paypal express checkout, all payment methods disappear from the chekout process. There's just a step whitout options.

I've ruled out problems with my theme, since this behaviour is the same with the default magento theme.

I've been dealing with this problem for days and nothing has worked.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Running some tests I see that when the onepage checkout page loads, the payment methods are there but hidden. When I click the "continue" button after selecting the shippment method, then the payment methods disappear. It seems after the shippmentMethods.save() function something happens that magento says there's no payment methods available. How can shippment methods affect payment methods? I've reviewed my configuration but can't find anything wrong.

Comment: When comparing with paypal express active and inactive I find the following:

When paypal is not active, when I click the continue button on the shipping method step, there’s an ajax load (checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/) that responds with the html that should go on the payment step: 
{"goto_section”:"payment”,"update_section”:{"name”:"payment-method”,"html":"<dl class=\"sp-methods\" id=\"checkout-payment-method-load\">\r\n <dt>\r\n <span class=\"no-display\">..."}}

When paypal is active, the response is: 
{"goto_section”:"payment”,"update_section”:{"name”:"payment-method”,"html":null}}

Comment: Paypal Express should show up in the shopping cart already, next to the proceed to checkout button.